# How to make a Horizontal Scrollbar Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just wondering how this could be achieved?
I saw this sidebar slideshow on http://store.steampowered.com/ where they advertise there games.
I have researched the web for awhile now but I am sure someone here knows how this is done?
Anyone know of any tutorials i can follow?
Thanks guys

*Edit*

Here is a picture from steam's website showing what i would like to accomplish
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Check this.](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

This one is one of my favourites. Try it.
You will love him.

Hope it helped. You can thank me later ;-)

[One more.](http://www.slidesjs.com/) They no longer manage it. But it's still awesome.

If this helps and solves what you were looking for. You can accept the answer.

Comment: That website in your comment is actually really good and helped loads thank you! but I am still confused how you can add a sidebar to the bottom of them?

Comment: @LawrenceWilliamTrigg [THIS](https://gist.github.com/marcoleong/1922743) will solve your issue. Cheers. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
There are multiple ways to achieve it, 
using Jquery or bootstrap carousal .

Check the below links.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp


http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/A2aZv/ 




Hope it will solve your requirement.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, im still rather confused about how a sidebar can be added to a slideshow, but i will read this webpage as it has useful information :)